# Play Framework Database Search

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a model class "Journey" in my project which has several methods to delete, create and list all of the journeys. I am using heroku and a postgresql database. I need to write a method that will return all journeys that have a similar address to one specified. I know the query structure would typically be something like `SELECT address FROM Journey WHERE address ~~ arguement` but I don't know what functions exist to do this in the play framework.

```
*public static void search(String address){
//query
//return matching journey results
}*
```

Comment: Yes and it is enabled in application.conf - ebean.default="models.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Model's `Finder` for an example:

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Journey extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    public static Finder<Integer, Journey> find
            = new Model.Finder<>(Integer.class, Journey.class);

    // other fields
    public String address;
    public String country;

}
```

so you can easily select records with:

```
List<Journey> allJourneys = Journey.find.all();
List<Journey> searchedJourneys = Journey.find.where().like("address", "%foo%").findList();
Journey firstJourney = Journey.find.byId(123);
```

In your base case you can add this to your model:

```
public static List<Journey> searchByAddress(String address){
    return find.where().like("address", "%"+address+"%").findList();
}
```

Etc. It returns whole objects with relations, so in big data sets it can be too heavy, you can or even should also use more optimized queries with Finder's chained methods like `select()`, `fetch()` etc to point which data you need at the moment.

There are also other possibilities in [Ebean's API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/index.html), anyway you need to declare which approach is most optimal for you.

BTW, it's worthy to examine existing sample applications, for an example `computer's database` to get familiar with this ORM.

**Edit**

For case insesitive searching there are additional Expressions i.e. `ilike` (instead of `like`) , `istartsWith`, `iendsWith`, `ieq`, `icontains`and `iexampleLike`. They does the same what version without `i` at the beginning.

You can preview them [in the API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/ExpressionList.html) as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is great. Thanks a lot its made things much clearer to me. Is there anyway to ignore case sensitivity with this "like" selector?